# Ruby on Rails - check if user have added any domain and if they have been approved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have models `Post` & `Domain`. My application works as, user have to submit a `domain` to be able to see all `posts` in `posts#index`.

Currently I am checking if user has submitted **any** `domain` & show them all `posts`. *I am doing it by:*

```
- if current_user.domains.blank?
  %p Please add a domain to see all posts
- else
  - @posts.each do |post|
  // each post
```

I want to change how I am doing it currently. All submitted `domains` needs to be **approved** (`status: true`) first & sometimes a user submit several domains.

What I am want to achieve now is to check if neither of `domains` has been `approved/status: true`, before show them `posts`.

So basically check if `current_user` has any `domain` and if so check it neither of `domains` has been *approved* (`status: true`) before show them `posts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as below

```
- if current_user.domains.approved_domains.blank?
  %p Please add a domain to see all posts
- else
  - @posts.each do |post|
  // each post
```

and add the scope `approved_domains` to Domain model as follow

```
scope :approved_domains, -> { where(status: true) }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Mahmoud. Appreciate your help :) If you find my question helpful for other, I would appreciate a thumbs-up :)